# Incrementing cell address by 2 in formula

Tags: excel, vba, macros, excel-formula

I have a formula like this:

```
=CONCATENATE("some text";D20;"sometext too ";E20)
```

I would like to auto fill these by dragging down the corner of the cell, but If I do that, I get this:

```
=CONCATENATE("some text";D20;"sometext too ";E20)
=CONCATENATE("some text";D21;"sometext too ";E21)
=CONCATENATE("some text";D22;"sometext too ";E22)
...
```

But I like to see that:

```
=CONCATENATE("some text";D20;"sometext too ";E20)
=CONCATENATE("some text";D22;"sometext too ";E22)
=CONCATENATE("some text";D24;"sometext too ";E24)
...
```

Any solution for that? I used Google for hours, but no solution.

VBA macro solution also acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=CONCATENATE("some text ",OFFSET(D$20,(ROWS(D$20:D20)-1)*2,0,1,1)," sometext too ",OFFSET(E$20,(ROWS(E$20:E20)-1)*2,0,1,1))
```

Comment: Note the commas (,) in CONCATENATE function.

Comment: It doesn't wortk even with (,) commas. :(

Comment: See this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d

Comment: [Image_link](http://i.imgur.com/UbZUNkq.png)

You can see on that image, that the OFFSET formula doesn't work properly.

Comment: This link gives me error: "This site can’t be reached. i.imgur.com took too long to respond."

Comment: Maybe your Internet provider or Proxy blocking this site.

Heres another one:
[Image link](http://s18.postimg.org/inugx51qx/doesntwork.png)

Comment: Do not use quotes in Text2 and Text4 where you are using OFFSET function. Quotes changes the function into a string.

Comment: I typed in the OFFSET formula parameters by myself from your code and it's working! Somehow if I copied from your doesn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're original problem is just that you are using semicolon ; instead of comma , in your formula.

Personally, I never use the =CONCATENATE formula these days.  You can achieve the same using &, for example:

="Some text "&A1&"some text too "&B1

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, it helped a little bit!